# Ninject bind property on view models to filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, ninject

I'm fairly new to ninject so you'll have to forgive the potentially stupid question. I have been able to successfully bind my own custom filter to controller actions, however my question is can I do the same to a property on a ViewModel? My scenario is thus:

I have a view model with properties that look like this

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    ...
    [PopulateWith(typeof(Country))]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

the attribute is is a simple class

```
public class PopulateWithAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type Type { get; }
    public PopulateWithAttribute(Type t)
    {
        Type = t;
    }
}
```

and all I want to be able to do is have a block of code that will run when a new instance of `CreateViewModel` is created, that will take the database context to hydrate the enumeration. I'm not sure if even an action filter is the correct route to go down like how you make custom authorization / logging functionality. It doesn't seem that the `BindFilter<>` has anything that points to being able to bind on properties...

A point in any direction or to any resources would be great.

Comment: But typically you instantiate your view models manually without involving any container, so the Ninject has no chance to run any custom code on it. So how do you create your view models? Or am I missing something?

Comment: well this is kind of what I'm asking but I guess you already answered it xD. If I can't run any custom ninject code, I dont think it's possible to hydrate a viewmodel property using an attribute? RE: "How do you create your view models", literally as you might think `= new ViewModel`. There are a few instances where Automapper is used to create the view model by mapping the database object directly to the view model.

Comment: Maybe you can create some generic factory of your view models and do all the required logic here.